# libgdx - AssetsManager - manage more than one location

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have two textures to manage.
One is in `Gdx.files.internal`, and one is in `Gdx.files.local`.

But it seems like the API limit me to manage one or the other, and not both simultaneously.

> manager = new AssetManager( *- takes only one resolver -* `);
>
> manager.setLoader(TextureAtlas.class, new TextureAtlasLoader( *- takes only one resolver -* ));

and this one take only one manager:

> Texture.setAssetManager(manager);

Is there a way to manage two resolvers?
Or build one resolver for two locations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a custom `FileHandleResolver` that first checks if the file exists in the first location, and if it does not exist, check the second location.

Maybe like this:

```
class MyFileHandleResolver implements FileHandleResolver {
    public FileHandle resolve(String fileName) {
        FileHandle localHandle = Gdx.files.local(fileName);
        if (localHandle.exists())
            return localHandle;
        else
            return Gdx.files.internal(fileName);    
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. One resolver with multiple locations works well. Instead of creating a file handler and than checking the existence, I'm using two different folders for internal and local files, so I check startsWith(..) and return the right resolver.